# How can I get the new name of a renamed file given its file descriptor/object?

Tags: python, c, linux, posix

When I open a file in Python with `f = open("filename.txt")`, I can access the filename using the `name` property (`file_object.name`). However, if that file is moved to another path, the `name` property isn't updated.

I can detect that the file has moved by opening the file again, calling stat and comparing the inode, but I couldn't find a way to get the new name of the original file. Is this possible? If not in Python, is there a way in C? Posix? Linux?

Comment: From the dupe: *however, if the file was moved or deleted since then, it may no longer be accurate*

Comment: Also on the dupe: the answer by zneak supports the file being moved, but it only worked on Mac OS X when I tested it, and it's not available on Python (F_GETPATH is not defined on Python's fcntl).